# deploy openshift 4 cluster on rhel

Tags: openshift, openshift-origin, okd

I want to deploy an openshift/okd cluster but i only have access to rhel machines , is there any work arround for me to have somehow the control plane machines in a rhel vm ?

> The bootstrap and control plane machines must use Red Hat Enterprise Linux CoreOS (RHCOS) as the operating system. However, the compute machines can choose between Red Hat Enterprise Linux CoreOS (RHCOS), Red Hat Enterprise Linux (RHEL) 7.9, or RHEL 8.4.

https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.9/installing/installing_platform_agnostic/installing-platform-agnostic.html#machine-requirements_installing-platform-agnostic

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible to install the control plane nodes in a RHEL virtual machine. The control plane installation is fully automated and the OpenShift installer will install RHCOS (or FCOS, when using OKD) and the control plane pods all together.

When choosing *user-provisioned infrastructure* (UPI) installation over the *installer-provisioned infrastructure* (IPI) you are responsible to create the virtual machines yourself. If possible in your environment you could let the installer reinstall your RHEL virtual machines during install. You van find more on [creating nodes](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.9/installing/installing_bare_metal/installing-bare-metal.html#creating-machines-bare-metal) during UPI in the documentation.

You could also -- as suggested in the comment -- use nested virtualization and install KVM on the RHEL virtual machine and create new virtual machines in there. You should check if nested virtualization is available in your environment.

Comment: is there any workround by doing a user provisionning installation ? maybe run a FCOS in kvm in top of the rhel machine ?

Comment: Sure. I've never tested that, but in theory it should work. The installer needs a couple of (virtual) machines, they can be on any kind of platform. Can't you just reuse the existing virtual machines? I've updated the answer with this possible workaround.